# Ambiguity in java generics 1.6 earlier version and the later

Tags: java, generics, java-6

Recently I encounter a weird problem with respect to `Java generics`. I simplified the problem with snippet below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Hello";
        System.out.println(blindlyReturnGetObject());
    }

    private static <T> T getObject() {
        return (T) new Object();
    }

    private static <T> T blindlyReturnGetObject() {
        return getObject();
    }
```

In case of `JDK 1.6.0_03` and earlier versions, we were getting infamous compilation error

```
type parameters of <T>T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds T,java.lang.Object
```

whereas this code works perfectly in `JDK 1.6.0_26` and later versions.

Is there anyway to get rid of this issue for earlier version of `jdk 1.6` since our build servers are still running in earlier version of `jdk 1.6`?

Comment: Under Java 1.5 this code works and compiles fine. Are you sure, that you didn't any mistake due compilation under earlier versions?

Comment: @Andremoniy As I mentioned we are getting this compilation error only if it is `1.6.0_0x`. I didnt try with `1.5`

Comment: If it is a bug in the compiler, why do you care which version is used for the runtime?

Comment: @jarnbjo edited my question now. I meant build machines and not prod servers. Apologies for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While googling related to this issue, I came across a bug raised in `sun` related to this `generics type inference` issue.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6302954

So this is found to be fixed in later versions of `jdk 1.6.0_20` and hence it was working in `jdk 1.6.0_26`

Thought its worth sharing.